# The use of String.matches() in Java

Tags: java

Let's see the following expressions about `String.matches()` in Java.

```
System.out.println("55CCEE".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));  //true
System.out.println("CC77HH".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));  //true
System.out.println("CC1156".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));  //true

System.out.println("С".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{1}"));       //false
System.out.println("СС".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{2}"));      //false
System.out.println("СС5588".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));  //false
System.out.println("СС5589".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));  //false
```

The first three cases look fine and work as expected. The rest of the cases, however seem to be failing and return `false` which wasn't expected. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the second set, you don't have a `C` in your string, you have a `С` which is `0xd0 0xa1` in UTF-8.

That char is Cyrillic - [CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x0421/index.html). See the [Cyrillic code chart (PDF)](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf) at unicode.org.

Comment: Well, can I do something to represent `C` as a string (*capital letter*) in the second set?

Comment: @Lion, simply copy & paste it in the class: `[С0-9A-Za-z]{6}`, where the first `С` is `\u0421`, or simply do: `[0-9A-Za-z\u0421]{6}` which would cause less confusion.

Comment: @Lion, Check the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) docs, "Unicode support" section and the  UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag.

Answer (score 2):

The 'C' character in the lines that are failing is a different Unicode character than the C in the [A-Z] character class.

```
    int unicodeFrom3rdLine = 'C';
    int unicodeFrom4thLine = 'С';
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(unicodeFrom3rdLine));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(unicodeFrom4thLine));
```

produces

```
    43
    421
```

Even though they look the same, they're actually different characters, the former being the normal C and latter being [Cyrillic](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/421/index.htm).